# Kendo Grid CRUD: how make update

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have a kendo ui grid with asp web api as backend. When i call the create method in the kendo ui, it's called the following method in web api

```
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(ProductDTO product)
{
    ...
    ...
    return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Now if i try to edit the item in the Kendo Ui Grid is called again the create method instead of the update method.
If i reload the page (so is called the read method of kendo ui grid), the update method works.

What's the problem? I have the following schema:

```
schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            fields: {
                Id: { editable: false, type: "number" },
                Name: { validation: { required: true } },
                Description: { editable: true },
                Price: { editable: true },
                Active: { type: "boolean" },
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the following transport (omitted some code)

```
$scope.tabellaProdotto = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: function () {
                return "api/Prodotti/GetProdottoPerTipoProdotto/" + productTypeMainSelected;
            },
            dataType: "json"
        },
        create: {
            url: "api/Prodotti/PostProdotto",
            dataType: "json",
            data: function (prodottoTmp) {
                ...
            },
            type: "POST"
        },
        update: {
            url: function (prodotto) {
                return "api/Prodotti/PutProdotto" + prodotto.Id
            },
            data: function (prodottoTmp) {
                ...
            },
            type: "PUT",
            dataType: "json"
```

UPDATE: the problem seems be the return of the web api action method:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = p.Id }, p);
```

Now works but the p object size dimension is very high: i must return the entire object?

Comment: Do you have update: url()  in your transport ?

Comment: yes!! I have edited the question. Anyway seems that the grid doesn't trace the created item...in effect if i reload the page the update works

Comment: so ur problem is update is calling properly... but updated values not reflected in UI when come back to UI from controller?? right now u r manually refreshing the page to see the updated result...Am i correct??

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the Grid is not getting the Json back in the right format.
Be sure to use the KendoMVC DataSourceRequest Object to return data in the right format.

Here is an example:

```
public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, MyViewModel data)
    {
        var result = UpdateBackend(data);
        return Json(result.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```